# How to get the row number of CSV

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, csv

How can I get the row number of CSV file?

I am using codeigniter here. I used *CSVreader* and HTML Table to show the data of CSV file in web.

My problem is, I want to get the CSV file rows number and NOT THE HTML TABLE. How can I do that? Or for the another help how can I also read the row number in CSV file?

**The codes for CSVreader :**

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->library('csvreader');

    $filePath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\bin\pdw_table.csv';

    $data['csvData'] = $this->csvreader->parse_file($filePath);

    $this->load->view('datacast_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the number of rows? (The row number is not associated with an entire file)

Comment: I think `count($data['csvData'])` will return the no. of rows.

Comment: Ok i will try that and get back after

Comment: i've got this erro "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\application\controllers\datacast_ctr.php on line 18"

Answer (score 0):

one way is :

```
$linecount = count(file('C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\bin\pdw_table.csv'));
```

also you can loop through file:

```
$myfile="C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\bin\pdw_table.csv";
$count = 0;
$filehandle = fopen($myfile, "r");
while(!feof($filehandle)){
  $line = fgets($filehandle);
  $count++;
}
fclose($filehandle);

echo $count;
```